# Sample request XML to create entity

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, blueprism

I am currently working on automating Entity creation request through web services using blue prism

Can someone please share me the request xml for entity creation in MS dynamics CRM

I have tried the below API and throwing error given in the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/create-entity-web-api).

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json

{
    "name": "Sample Account",
    "creditonhold": false,
    "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
    "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
    "revenue": 5000000,
    "accountcategorycode": 1
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide soap xml format please?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the error that I am getting when I used the above. I have added the headers as well.

Comment: I have tried this however I am getting bad request error. Can you please help me on this

Comment: Sorry, I can't - I haven't ever worked with Dynamics :)

Answer (score 0):

Using CRM 2011 Endpoint.

Note: In my case only Account Name was required and Account number was required.

Using XMLHTTP Request

```
 var entity = {};
entity.AccountNumber = "123456789";
entity.Name = "Account from 2011 API";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", encodeURI("YourORGURL" + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet"), false);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        this.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 201) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText).d;
            var newEntityId = result.AccountId;
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

---

using Jquery

```
var entity = {};
entity.AccountNumber = "123456789";
entity.Name = "Account from 2011 API";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: "YourORGURL" + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet",
    data: JSON.stringify(entity),
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var result = data.d;
        var newEntityId = result.AccountId;
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```